# Cannot increase the accuracy of the neural network

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have been learning CNN implementation in PyTorch recently, and I tried to write my own code with CNNs to process the CIFAR images. I got very low accuracy in the beginning, which, while going through the code and fixing the mistakes, I managed to pull up to 40% - 45%.

I am not able to increase it beyond that, and was wondering, if I could get some help, and comments with what could be done to increase it.

Here is the code which I used to create the data :

```
import torch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pickle


REBUILD_DATA = False  #True


files = ["C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_1", "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_2",
         "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_3", "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_4",
         "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_5", "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\Test_batch"]


file_names = ["training_data_conv_batch_1.npy", "training_data_conv_batch_2.npy", "training_data_conv_batch_3.npy",
              "training_data_conv_batch_4.npy", "training_data_conv_batch_5.npy", "training_data_conv_test_batch.npy"]


LABELS = {0 : "AIRPLANE", 1 : "AUTOMOBILE", 2 : "BIRD", 3 : "CAT", 4 : "DEER", 5 : "DOG", 6 : "FROG", 7 : "HORSE",
          8 : "SHIP", 9 : "TRUCK"}


def create_training_data(file, ctr):
    training_data = []

    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        data = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')

    r = int(data[b'data'][0].shape[0] / 3)

    if REBUILD_DATA:
        for n in range(len(data[b'labels'])):
          images = np.zeros((32, 32, 3))

          r_matrix = data[b'data'][n][:r]
          g_matrix = data[b'data'][n][r:2 * r]
          b_matrix = data[b'data'][n][2 * r:3 * r]

          counter = 0

          print(n, end=" ")

          for i in range(32):
              print("|", end = "")
              for j in range(32):
                  images[i][j] = [r_matrix[counter]/255, g_matrix[counter]/255, b_matrix[counter]/255]
                  counter += 1
          training_data.append([images, np.eye(10)[data[b'labels'][n]]])
          print()

        np.random.shuffle(training_data)
        np.save(file_names[ctr], training_data)


ctr = 0
if REBUILD_DATA:
    for file in files:
        print("BATCH ", ctr + 1)
        create_training_data(file, ctr)
        ctr += 1
        print()

    for i in file_names:
        training_data = np.load(i, allow_pickle=True)
        for n in range(5):
            plt.imshow(training_data[n][0])  # , cmap = "gray")
            print(LABELS[np.argmax(training_data[n][1])])
            plt.show()
```

Here is the code of the CNN :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import numpy as np

files = ["C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_1", "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_2",
         "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_3", "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_4",
         "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\data_batch_5", "C:\TORCH_CNN\CIFAR\cifar-10-batches-py\Test_batch"]


file_names = ["training_data_conv_batch_1.npy", "training_data_conv_batch_2.npy", "training_data_conv_batch_3.npy",
              "training_data_conv_batch_4.npy", "training_data_conv_batch_5.npy", "training_data_conv_test_batch.npy"]


LABELS = {0 : "AIRPLANE", 1 : "AUTOMOBILE", 2 : "BIRD", 3 : "CAT", 4 : "DEER", 5 : "DOG", 6 : "FROG", 7 : "HORSE",
          8 : "SHIP", 9 : "TRUCK"}


device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")


print()
print()


class CIDAR_CONV_NETS(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 3, 1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, 1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 3)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 3)
        self.conv5 = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3)

        self.toLinear = None
        if self.toLinear == None:
            x = self.convolution(torch.randn(32, 32, 3).view(-1, 3, 32, 32))
            self.toLinear = x[0].shape[0] * x[0].shape[1] * x[0].shape[2]

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.toLinear, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(512, 512)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(512, 10)


    def convolution(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        conv = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv5(x)), (2, 2))
        return conv


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convolution(x).view(-1, self.toLinear)
        h1 = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        h2 = F.relu(self.fc2(h1))
        h3 = F.relu(self.fc3(h2))
        h4 = self.fc4(h3)
        return h4      





def train(net, x, y, batch_size):
    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr = 0.0001)  
    loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()    
    EPOCHS = 50
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        for batch in range(0, len(x), batch_size):
            batch_x = x[batch : batch + batch_size].view(-1, 3, 32, 32)
            batch_y = y[batch : batch + batch_size]   #.view(-1, 3, 32, 32) .uniform_(0, batch_size)
            net.zero_grad()
            output = net(batch_x)
            loss = loss_function(output, torch.max(batch_y, 1)[1])  #torch.max(batch_y, 1)[1]
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        print("epoch : ", epoch + 1, end = "   ||   ")
        print("loss : ", loss)





def test(net, x, y, batch_size_test):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    #step_size = int(len(x) / batch_size_test)
    print()
    ctr = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in range(0, len(x), batch_size_test):
            test_batch_x = x[batch: batch + batch_size_test].view(-1, 3, 32, 32)
            test_batch_y = y[batch: batch + batch_size_test]
            predicted_output = net(test_batch_x)
            print(ctr, end = " ")
            ctr += 1
            for i in range(len(test_batch_x)):
                if torch.argmax(predicted_output[i]) == torch.argmax(test_batch_y[i]):
                    correct += 1
                total += 1
                print(".", end = "")
            print(".")
    return correct/total




NETWORK = True

conv_net = CIDAR_CONV_NETS().to(device)
#print(conv_net)


if NETWORK:
    BATCH_SIZE = 100
    BATCH_SIZE_TEST = 1000
    BATCH_NO = 1
    for file in file_names:
        if file == "training_data_conv_test_batch.npy":
            training_data = np.load(file, allow_pickle=True)
            print("TRAINING COMPLETE.")
            print()
            print("TEST BATCH : ")
            X = torch.tensor([i[0] for i in training_data], dtype=torch.float32).cuda()
            Y = torch.tensor([i[1] for i in training_data], dtype=torch.int64).cuda()
            accuracy = test(conv_net, X, Y, BATCH_SIZE_TEST)
            print()
            print("Accuracy of the network : ", accuracy*100, end = "")
            print("%")
        else:
            training_data = np.load(file, allow_pickle=True)
            print("DATA BATCH : ", BATCH_NO)
            X = torch.tensor([i[0] for i in training_data], dtype=torch.float32).cuda() 
            Y = torch.tensor([i[1] for i in training_data], dtype=torch.int64).cuda()   
            train(conv_net, X, Y, BATCH_SIZE)
            print()
            print()
            BATCH_NO += 1
```

I would appreciate help!
Thank you!

Comment: Im not 100% sure but I dont think Pytorch can do backpropagation on any other function but ```forward```. So the problem might be that it doesnt train your conv layers in the ```convolution``` function. I also dont understand why you use an extra function for that? What is that ```toLinear``` thing exactly?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response!

To the best of my knowledge, as PyTorch does not have a means to flatten the matrices at the and of convolution and pooling, I am creating a random 32x32x3 tensor and preforming convolution operations on it to find out the dimensions of the end vector for the fully connected layer at initialization.

ToLinear variable is set to None at initialization, and if it is none, above operation is run to get the dimensions of final matrix and the required dimension of the flattened vector is calculated.

That's why there was an extra function for conv layers!

Comment: could you try write the conv layers you use for the acutal input directly in the forward function?

Comment: Yes, I did it and it improved the performance. I further shuffled the data before every epoch, ad that also improved it a bit.
But I have managed to pull it i the rage 48%-52%. I am not able to improve it beyond that..
I am not sure about other ways to improve the accuracy...

Comment: try to use softmax at the last dense layer and MSE loss